# JBOSS Standalone Interfaces

Tags: java, networking, jboss, server

In the standalone.xml file for JBOSS 6.4 there is the interfaces section, What is the unsecured section shown, when is it used?

```
   <interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <!--
          ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
          ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL
          -->
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMI/IIOP (remote method invocation, internet inter-orb protocol) is used with the JacORB subsystem to provide CORBA/IIOP (remote) access to enterprise beans deployed in a JBoss Application Server, as defined by the EJB specification.

ref: http://jbossiiop.jboss.org/

Using IIOP, clients (both java and other CORBA compliant implementations) can access your EJBs via this protocol.

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi-iiop/index.html

simple tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi-iiop/tutorial.html

It can be secured via SSL, see Securing JBoss Services:
https://www.redhat.com/promo/summit/2010/presentations/jbossworld/optimize-secure-manage/thurs/rbroeckelmann-310-security/JBossWorldPresentation--Security-JBoss-Services-v1_10.pdf
or google for more information.

If you are not using JacORB/IIOP directly, then you can probably remove the module and subsystem references to the jacorb as well as the insecure interface without negative consequences.